# É possível utilizar o PHPMailer no meu localhost?

Tags: php, phpmailer

É possível utilizar o PHPMailer no meu localhost? Eu já tentei diversas vezes. Estou tentando enviar e-mails com gmail (eu não sei se isso é possível). Eu preciso possuir um domínio para utilizar o phpmailer?

Comment: Pode descrever sua configuração do localhost?

Comment: Se a sua configuração de email do Gmail estiver correta, sim! caso queira enviar sem usar configuração de SMTP externa, instale um servidor SMTP na sua máquina.

Comment: Eu respondi uma pergunta similar à algum tempo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45146/formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-n%C3%A3o-funciona/45152#45152

Comment: Sorry, brothers.